# how to return a xml from nusoap

Tags: nusoap

I have a webservice created with nusoap, actually returns me a string
i want to do  send name and lastname to my web service,my webservice must save this information and give me an id( autoincrement) y it does, but I want something like this

send:
nombrepersona ="ozzy"
apellidopersona="osbourne"

I get the id(autoincrement), example

```
1
```

but i want a xml something like

```
<id>1</id>
```

or

```
 <id>1</id>    
 <name>ozzy</name>
 <lastname>osbourne</lastname>
```

or

```
<response>
  <id>1</id>    
  <name>ozzy</name>
  <lastname>osbourne</lastname>
</response>
```

### consume from my webservice

```
<?php 
error_reporting(1);
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/nusoap/server3.php?wsdl",'wsdl');
$nombre="ozzy";
$apellido="osbourne";
$params =array(       
   'nombrepersona'=>$nombre,
   'apellidopersona'=>$apellido);
$result = $client->call('insertar',array($params));
?>
```

### definition from my method

```
<?php
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Persona',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(          
        'nombrepersona' => array('name' => 'nombrepersona', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'apellidopersona' => array('name' => 'apellidopersona', 'type' => 'xsd:string')         
    )
);

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'ArrayOfPersona',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Persona[]')               
    ),
    'tns:Persona'
);

$server->register(
    'insertar',                        // Nombre del método
    array('datos' =>'tns:Persona'),       // Parámetros de entrada
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'),      // Parámetros de salida
    SOAP_SERVER_NAMESPACE,                // Nombre del workspace
    SOAP_SERVER_NAMESPACE.'#insertar',    // Acción soap
    'rpc',                                // Estilo
    'encoded',                            // Uso
    'Insertar datos de la persona'        // Documentación
);
?>
```

function

---

```
<?php
function insertar($datos) 
{       
    require_once('conectar.php');
    mysql_select_db($database,$conexion);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query="INSERT INTO personas (`nombrep`,`apellidop`) VALUES('".$datos['nombrepersona']."','".$datos['apellidopersona']."')";
    $record=mysql_query($query,$conexion) or die ((mysql_error()));
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
    return $id;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution, definition output must be like this:

array('response'=>'XSD:Array')

and return of function like this:

return array('id'=>$id , etc);